Choose a subset of n values from a set whereby the sum of the subset cannot be achieved with less than n values from the set
Not a mathematician (I'm a programmer) so please bear with me.
I've written a program to solve a Subset Sum and am trying to generate some test data to stress-test it.  After attempting to do this manually I then switched to asking three different AI engines with varying but incomplete success.  This was my request:

Generate a set of 50 money values (i.e. containing 2 decimal places),
both positive and negative, whose absolute value is between 10 and
100.  Then identify a positive total that can be reached by the
summing of no less than 6 of the values.  Output the full set, the
summed total of the subset, and the subset.

However no matter which 6 values were selected, my program always found a solution using 4 or even 3 values.  (I rephrased the constraint several times to no avail.)
I wondered (don't laugh) whether using prime numbers would help.

Generate the first 50 prime numbers, randomise the order and divide
all of them by 100.  Then choose an arbitrary subset of 6 of them and
tell me the set, the subset and the sum of them.

(Note that I avoided the inclusion of negative values for this attempt.)  But my program found a solution using 2 values.
I can't help feeling though that there may be a number set or sequence that fits what I'm looking for, however not being a mathematician I don't even know what to search for.  Can you good folks point me in the right direction please?
Edit:  My goal is I'm trying to make my program work hard for the stress test.  I want it to have to find a 6-value solution, but it's getting off easy because it's finding a 2-value solution (for example) that sums to the same target total.  For example this was the 6-value subset chosen by the AI for the "prime numbers" test, summing to 3.18:

However the program found a 2-value solution (the 6th and 33rd values) that summed to the same total of 3.18:

Edit 2:  I seem to be having trouble making myself understood so I asked the AI to phrase the question in mathematical terms.  I hope this helps.  (Note: The image contains an error - see Edit 3.)

Edit 3:  Correction to the above image - the condition should state "there should be no smaller subset of the original set S (not just T) whose sum equals that of T", i.e. for the subset T⊆S where ∣T∣=6, there should be no subset T′⊆S with ∣T′∣<∣T∣ such that ∑x∈T′x=∑x∈Tx.

Not following.  Your list consists of $50$ values between $10$ and $100$, right?  So taking $6$ times the maximum in your list will need six values to reach.  Or have I misunderstood something?

@lulu I'll Edit to provide more context.

Can you clarify the "whose absolute value is between 10 and 100"? Did you want them to be from 0.10 to 1.00?

@CalvinLin Think of it as almost between 10.01 and 99.99 (but really it's between 10.00 and 100.00).  My question contains two examples of what was asked of the AI (in block quotes); in the second case I used prime numbers for their properties, but to test the program I wanted my sample set to be more complex than "integers" so I took the shortcut of subsequently dividing them by 100 to resemble money values.

Integers, are equally complex to your ,integers divided by 100, mathematically.

None of your chatgpt framed questions can be answered here(am programmer as well, maybe you can ask at SO) The only mathematical question you're asking is the irreducibility test. Which chatgpt have framed wrong, Since xi is only positive,not zero,negative the condition there exist no T' belong to T such that sum of T'= sum of T is always true. chatgpt should have said T' belongs to S, n(T')<n(T)

@redoc The mathematical question is really the only one I want answered. Thanks for highlighting the term "irreducibility test" for me.
ChatGPT concedes your point:
"Correct, what I should have said is that there should be no smaller subset of the original set S (not just T) whose sum equals that of T. So the irreducibility test isn't just about checking within T, but rather ensuring that there isn't any subset T′⊆S (where ∣T′∣<∣T∣) that achieves the same sum as T.
For the subset T⊆S where ∣T∣=6, there should be no subset T′⊆S with ∣T′∣<∣T∣ such that ∑x∈T′x=∑x∈Tx."

Maybe we can add a little context to this...  I think that you need a bigger "universe", or a larger set of numbers...  For example, like $10$ decimal digits and not 2.  To try to make this clear think of binary numbers:  1, 2, 4, 8, 16...  You only need ten of these numbers to generate every number from one to 1,000, and only twenty of these to generate every number up to and past 1,000,000.   Another example that YOU came up with: primes.  Goldbach's conjecture is that EVERY number is the sum of 2 primes.  I'll continue this in the next comment...

There is a theory called "sumsets".  It is about how many different numbers you can get by sums of numbers from a set.  Essentially:  When you have a set of $n$ numbers, you usually get fairly close to $n^2$ numbers that are sums of those numbers.  When you add four numbers together, you still get fairly close to $n^4$ DIFFERENT possible results.  So if you try to use six numbers, you're going to have to select those numbers from a set of around $n^6$ numbers.  i.e. If you start with 100 numbers, you're going to need a possible solution set of around $100^6$.

By the way, interesting to hear what ChatGPT says!

I don't see what is wrong with the suggestion of @lulu. If you take the six largest of your $50$ numbers, you won't be able to get their sum using fewer than six of the $50$ numbers. Isn't that what you want?

@GerryMyerson Ohhhh....thank you - I didn't realise that's what lulu meant.  Her (and your) statement is correct, however my program "optimises" the search by first sorting the numbers in descending order so it can quickly avoid and abandon unfruitful avenues.  What this means is a solution consisting of the six largest numbers would be found immediately, which is good in normal circumstances but in the case of a stress-test is not very useful.

Then I don't know what you want, although I suspect you can't get it. If you take $50$ 4-sig-fig numbers, probably almost all the sums of six of them can also be expressed as a sum of a smaller set. The idea of user @MathFont probably only works if you take logs of primes to several decimals.

OK, I'm going to make believe that I understand what you are asking for, and I'm going to give four solutions, the first three of which have serious drawbacks.
I have added a fifth solution.
I think you want a set $S$ of $50$ numbers such that, no matter which subset $T$ of size six and positive sum you pick, you can't get that sum by picking fewer than six members of $S$.
First solution: simply let $S$ be a set of $50$ negative numbers (I note that the original statement of your question allowed $S$ to have negative members). Now there is no subset $T$ with positive sum, so, vacuously, if a subset $T$ of size six has positive sum, then you can't get that sum by picking fewer than six members of $S$. The drawback of this solution is too obvious to state. From here on, we assume all members of $S$ are positive.
Second solution (suggested by lulu): let $S=\{\,1,2,4,8,16,\dotsc,2^{49}\,\}$ be the set of the first $50$ powers of two. It is well-known that all sums of distinct members of $S$ are different, so, in particular, no sum of six is also a sum of fewer than six. The drawback here is that $2^{49}= 562949953421312$, whereas in the original question the numbers were required to be between $10$ and $100$, with only two decimal places.
Third solution (suggested by MathFont): let $S=\{\,\log2,\log3,\log5,\dotsc,\log229\,\}$, the logarithms of the first $50$ primes (natural logs, or base ten logs, or any other base, it doesn't matter, as long as you pick one base and stick to it). Any sum of six different numbers from $S$ is $\log n$ for some $n$ which is a product of six different primes, and no such $n$ can be written as a product of fewer primes (nor as a product of more primes, nor as a product of six other primes). $\log229\div\log2<8$, so you can scale these numbers up to lie between $10$ and $100$.
The drawback here is that you can have two large integers very close to each other, each a product of distinct primes taken from the first $50$, one a product of six primes, the other a product of fewer than six primes. Lehmer discusses this sort of thing in his paper, On a problem of Störmer, Illinois J. Math. 8 (1964) 57-79; the example $2\times5\times13\times19\times41=101270$, $7\times17\times23\times37=101269$ should indicate the kind of thing that can happen. $\log101270-\log101269\simeq0.00001$ so you would need the members of $S$ to be given to five decimal places just to handle the primes up to $41$.
Fourth solution: let $S=\{\,1,7,13,19,25,\dotsc,295\,\}$, the first $50$ numbers that leave a remainder $1$ when you divide by six. Any six of these numbers will add up to a multiple of six; no (nonempty) sum of fewer than six of these numbers will add up to a multiple of six. They aren't quite in the range $10$ to $100$, but they are closer to that range than the powers of two, and no decimal places at all are needed.
Fifth solution: Let $S$ consist of any $50$ numbers of the form $n+0.1$, where $n$ is an integer, $10\le n\le99$. The sum of any six of these numbers will be of the form $m+0.6$ for some integer $m$, and no sum of fewer than six members of $S$ will be of this form.
I hope this helps.

Oh, I like your (fourth) solution!  Perhaps it's trivial for you but for me it's the inspired Fibonacci-like sequence I was looking for!  (I temporarily broke my program while trying to incorporate enough digits to implement MathFont's logarithm approach so when I unbreak it I'll implement this approach and report back.)

I've not yet had a chance to unbreak my program, however your inspiring fourth and fifth solutions meet my requirements so I'm marking this as the correct answer - thank you.

If I understand your question, exponentiating the entries of S creates a set T for which you ask the following: a certain product of six elements of T cannot be expressed as a product of five or fewer elements of T.
This is satisfied by T= any set of prime numbers.
You can of course employ scale changes  to position them in any desired prescribed interval.

Thanks for your answer.  I had to ask ChatGPT what you meant and it came back with:  "The responder is thinking in terms of products rather than sums, which is not aligned with your original problem. They are drawing on properties of prime numbers that make their products unique and non-factorable by subsets, but this logic applies to multiplicative structures, not additive ones.
Your original question involves sum irreducibility, so the suggestion about primes doesn't directly apply unless you were working with multiplicative combinations instead of additive sums."

Please stay away from chatgpt. It doesn't know anything, and you don't know anything, and that's a mixture guaranteed to produce nonsense and failure. What MathFont wants you to do is take the logarithms of those prime numbers for your additive problem. Take $T$ to be the primes, and $S$ to be the logs of those primes. $T$ has the property you want for products, so $S$ will have that property for sums.

@GerryMyerson Thanks for another clarification - will try the logarithms of primes next.  As for ChatGPT, I was using it as a way of trying to understand and to make myself understood.  Perhaps I should have just posted my question with "Explain it to me like I'm 5".  :-)

The fly in the ointment with logs of primes is that, for example, $\log 7$ and $\log2+4\log3+\log5+4\log11-\log13-4\log19$ agree to seven decimal places.
